# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; The prefix for element ; is not bound

Tags: xml, soap

I am trying to access my soap service method from postman... with following Body in the XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
    <soap:Body>
        <EchoTransaction xmlns="https://localhost:7003/TestService/service/TestServiceServiceImpl">
            <userName>faseeh</userName>
            <password>haris</password>
            <ping>hello</ping>
        </EchoTransaction>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

but it is throwing error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode>
            <faultstring>org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 114; The prefix &quot;soap&quot; for element &quot;soap:Envelope&quot; is not bound.</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">WorkStation</ns1:hostname>
            </detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

myURL is: https://localhost:7003/TestService/service/TestServiceServiceImpl?op=EchoTransaction

I tried the xml schema tag changes but didnt solve my problem.

Please help..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error means exactly what it says: you have an element with a namespace prefix

```
<soap:Envelope...>
```

and there is no `xmlns:soap="..."` declaration that binds the soap prefix to a namespace URI.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error when there was a double entry of a link out of nowhere, likely done by hand as a quick workaround for a failing link in one of the two lines, and then forgotten to drop:

```bash
<item_a_link>https://failing_link<item_b_link>
<item_a_link>https://working_link<item_a_link>
```

should be:

```bash
<item_a_link>https://working_link<item_a_link>
```